# Define variables globally with if statements in Gitlab CI CD

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, continuous-deployment, cicd

I want to set my variable $ENVIRONMENT to "int" if the $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH ist equal to "development". If the commit branch is equal to "main" I want to set the variable to the value "prod". This has to happen gloablly because every stage and job has to be able to access it.

I allready tried to set it within the job using rules but that didn't set the variable globally so it isn't really an option.

```
rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "development"
      variables:
        ENVIRONMENT: "int"
```